# Convert php and mysql web application into offline desktop application

Tags: php, mysql, desktop-application

I have made a web application with php and mysql in wamp server. Now i want to convert it into desktop application for windows platform which will run offline as complete desktop application.

Please anybody help me. Because it so so important for my job place...

Thanks..

Comment: This website isn't for such broad questions, please do some research in building Windows applications and have a look at MSDN for tutorials and guides. There are tonnes of resources everywhere.

Comment: Read about https://electron.atom.io/ - you can`t convert by magic button "convert" but you can make desktop application using javascript.

Comment: Thx bro. But is it possible to compile it into a msi file?

Answer (score 2):

**nightrain** - https://github.com/kjellberg/nightrain

> PHP Nightrain is a packager written in Python for the PHP Programming Language. Using this tool you can convert your PHP/HTML/CSS/Javascript application to a Native Desktop Application. Currently, PHP Nightrain supports the Windows, Mac (OS X) and the Linux operating systems.

**PHP Desktop** - https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

> PHP desktop GUI framework with HTML5 Chrome/IE engine.

Comment: Downloads for Nightrain don't work as the domain has been stolen.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out exeoutput for php. It's a paid application priced at one time fee of USD 99. They also have discounts for students and teachers.

It outputs the file in a single exe file format for Windows and the exe can be run as a standalone file without installation and portable in a USB too with complete web server, chrome browser packaged as an application.
You don't need to rewrite your existing html, php code and can use it as it is.

You can also connect to sqlite and mysql databases if your app is database dependent and place the database either outside the main exe or embedded inside it. The latest version is packaged with php 7.3 which you can upgrade if needed. All major php modules are included by default

Your complete PHP, HTML java script code is protected since it's inside of an exe which doesn't extract when running so no one can reverse engineer the code and redistribute your app. You can also set a splash screen png image, an expiration date so just in case some one redistributes it, it will become invalid and unusable after the expiration date. changing the system clock will not allow reuse of the expired app.

I have been using it for some time and that's the only solution i found which was polished enough for use.
I tried PHP Desktop before but the code is exposed in that case and end user can modify your code and redistribute it in PHP Desktop.

Note: I am not associated with exeoutput in any way but found the app so useful hence the lengthy answer.